# Data extension linkage to contact record

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, contactbuilder

Is is it mandatory that Data extensions should be linked directly to the contact record prior to being linked to different data extensions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to link Data Extensions (*or 'Attribute Sets' in the context of Contact Builder*) if you specifically require a cardinal relationship between them. For example, you want to create a relationship between two Data Extensions (Customer Orders DE -> Products DE).

If you are storing the Contact Key value in each DE and don't need to create a cardinal relationship, then you can link all Data Extensions directly to the Contact Record within an Attribute Group without needing to 'chain' them.

Note that you will need a minimum of one Population (formerly a root relationship) before you can create cardinal relationships to other Data Extensions in Attribute Groups. Without a Population, your Contacts will fail to enter an Interaction. Note that if you already have a root relationship in an Attribute Group, these still work, but you can't create new root relationships.

Comment: Thanks @EliotHarper.
Can I also assume this to be true that each attribute group can contain multiple lists. And in turn these lists can also have multiple attributes.

Comment: Only Data Extensions can be used as Attribute Sets in an Attribute Group, not email Lists. But if you are referring to Data Extensions, then yes, an Attribute Group can contain links to one or many Data Extensions.

Comment: Yes I meant data extensions only @Eliotharper!
I'll take care to be precise here onwards :)